# Comparing a variable to the last number in an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, compare

For example, i want to do something like this:

```
if("randomint" == "lastvariableoffarray"){
    //Something will happen
}
```

The question is, how do i specify the last viariable of a variable. For example if an array has 5 different int variables, how do i pick the last one, last one being number 5 or [4].

EDIT: Sorry i meant a 2 dimensional array. so lets say i want to compare to the last number of the "second array". By that i mean: Examplearray[][thisone].

Comment: What is your Question?
Please Add more detail to your Question...

Answer (score 0):

To find last variable of the array you can use array length.

```
lastItem = array[array.length]
```

Or, if the language you are using has 0-based array indexing (if first element is at position 0) :

```
lastItem = array[array.length - 1]
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `C#`, so it would be 0-based in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars =[["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],["Oneplus", "Samsung", "Iphone"],["Apple", "Banana", "Pear"]];
var lastvariableoffarray = cars.length -1;
var randomint = "Pear"; 
if(randomint == cars[2][lastvariableoffarray])
{

    alert("whoop");
}
```

Comment: This code would not compile. You need to use the equality operator (==) like this: `if(randomint == lastvariableoffarray)`

Comment: Quite simple, but remember that this is `C#`, not `Javascript`

Comment: my bad thought it was for javascript